# Talend XPath syntax problems when trying to access Google Translate API Response

Tags: json, xpath, talend, google-translate

I am trying to parse multiple translations in Talend using a tExtractJSONFields component.  I am not that familiar with XPath.

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Bonjour"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "Au Revoir"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I am only translating a single element, this configuration works:

[image: Single Translated Response - Working Configuration]

However when I am requesting multiple translations, I am trying to guess at the syntax to pull out the different translatedText values in the response.

For example, this doesn't work it seems:

[image: Expecting 4 responses from Google Translate]

Any help appreciated. I am sending 4 items for translation so expect an array of 4 JSON objects each with a "translatedText" property.

Updated:

Response with 4 items is as below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "translations": [
      {
        "translatedText": "Product 1"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "04/12/1984"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "Withdrawn"
      },
      {
        "translatedText": "national"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try this:

[image]

I get close, but all the output looks like it has square brackets around it indicating an array of sorts.

[image]

And I have tried the above with "translations[0]/translatedText[0]" as the XPath query and it does the same thing.

Comment: can you post the entire response you are receiving from google in case of 4 items

Answer (score 1):

Actually this seems to have worked:

[image]